Vim cursor doesn't move in the align indent
Im a newbie Vim user.
Whenever I press 'Enter' to get to the next line, the cursor jump back to the start of the line.
I want it to stay at the indent of the previous line. How can i config it.
<> as my cursor
When I press Enter, it jump like this
if (True):
    doSomething()
<>

And I want it to be like this
if (True):
    doSomething()
    <>


Just set autoindent ? Tried something from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+preserve+indent ?

Indentation procedure depends on a file type. For untyped files it is switched off by default.
You can type a command :options (or click menu "Edit"->"Settings Window" in GVim) and navigate to section #15 to see your indent settings. Most probably you want autoindent or smartindent on.
If your file is written in some programming language (like Python or such) check that the file type was detected successfully and that special indentation is enabled. (The command is called :filetype, the help topic is :help filetype).
You can also set file type manually (:help :setf) but the automatic indentation only works when enabled by :filetype command anyway.
Don't forget to update your vimrc also.
